# Is there a Django application similar to Drupal's Organic Groups module?

Tags: django, drupal, permissions, organic-groups

Basically I am looking for the following:

- Groups can be created by users of the site.
- Users can apply to join a group.
- Every group has a group administrator which can approve or reject applications to join a group. Also, they can remove members from a group.
- Content can be created which is associated with the group. Only group members can create content. Users who are not group members can view this content but not create/modify the content.

Are there any Django applications which can help implement these requirements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only one that I'm aware of is part of the [Pinax project](http://pinaxproject.com/docs/dev/groups/).  It doesn't meet all of these out of the box, but can be expanded pretty easily to get these features.